Elasticsearch Python client not removing a dead node
We have a cluster with 6 Elasticsearch instances (version 8.13) in Google Cloud (self-managed with docker swarm). We have a few indices with 2 replicas each. We had to upgrade our cluster (increase the amount of memory), so the plan was to shut down one instance, increase the amount of memory, run it back up, and repeat for every other instance.
Configuration of the client is as follows:
  hosts:
    - scheme: http
      host: "es8_node"
      port: 9200
  timeout: 10
  sniff_on_start: True
  sniff_on_node_failure: True
  sniff_timeout: 15

When the first instance got back up, cluster health was quickly restored back up to 100%, and all shards were assigned, but the response was still very high on some requests.
Even after an hour, some requests were still having very high response time, but I've managed to find this record in the logs of the Python service:
Node <Urllib3HttpNode(http://10.0.3.53:9200)> has failed for 271 times in a row, putting on 30 second timeout.

It turned out that the instance that I restarted got a new IP address, and even after so many failures, it hasn't been removed from the list of nodes. Why? These retries and resurrects of this node were causing high response time.
Shouldn't sniff_on_node_failure solve this? In the list of nodes I get from Elasticsearch (_cat/nodes), this node is not listed anymore. Why is it not removed?
